# Conectar a la base de datos con hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy comenzando con hibernate. Tengo que hacer un ejercicio con siwng, la idea seria que al igual que con las query de sql pongo un boton conectar y otro de desconectar con estos metodos

```
 public Connection Conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.login, this.password);
            if (conn != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión a base de datos " + bd + " lista");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        conn = null;
        String mensaje = "La conexion a la  base de datos " + bd + " ha terminado";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
    }
```

Si es posible hacer algo parecido.
Ya tengo el hibernate configurado y todo.
Habia pensado en algo asi

```
public Connection Conectar() {
try {
SessionFactory instancia = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = instancia.openSession();
} catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return session ;
    }
```

Comment: Falta la pregunta con el problema que estás encarando.

Comment: LA pregunta es clara si se puede hacer algo parecido a como se hace en sql con le boton conectar, lee porque viene